# HTML & JavaScript - Conditional formatting is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, conditional-formatting

I am trying to create some conditional formatting using JavaScript and HTML.

Basically I have a table with the following fields:

```
table
system
timestamp
total_amount
amount_used
amount_free
```

What I want based on the value of the column amount_free to change the colour of the field.

In this case if my column amount_free is 0 € then I want to have the red colour on my cell.

For that I am using the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#table_id td.amount_free').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == '0 €') {
      $(this).css('background-color', '#f00');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table,
td {
  word-wrap: keep-all;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 3px;
}

,
th {
  text-align: left;
}

,
th {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

,
td {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 10pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table style=width:100%>
  <tr>
    <th>table</th>
    <th>system</th>
    <th>timestamp</th>
    <th>total_amount</th>
    <th>amount_used</th>
    <th>amount_free</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>amount_values</td>
    <td>users</td>
    <td>2019-07-18 00:00:00</td>
    <td>398 €</td>
    <td>179 €</td>
    <td>0 €</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But it doesn't return any colour. Only the table without formating.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please provide a formatted code

Comment: The selector `'#table_id td.amount_free'` doesn't refer to any element, so your jquery script basically does nothing

Comment: There are no classes on the `<td>` either so `td.amount_free` has no matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#table_id .amount_free_value').each(function() {
    const value = $(this).text().split('€')[0];
    if (value == 0) {
      $(this).css('background-color', '#f00');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table,
td {
  word-wrap: keep-all;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 3px;
}

,
th {
  text-align: left;
}

,
th {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

,
td {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 10pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table style="width:100%" id="table_id">
  <tr>
    <th>table</th>
    <th>system</th>
    <th>timestamp</th>
    <th>total_amount</th>
    <th>amount_used</th>
    <th>amount_free</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>amount_values</td>
    <td>users</td>
    <td>2019-07-18 00:00:00</td>
    <td>398 €</td>
    <td>179 €</td>
    <td class="amount_free_value">0 €</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What you are trying to check is somehow wrong, you have the currency inside the text string. You don't have an id for the table and neither a class or some attribute on the `amount_free` value from the table.

You can do it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

you have some typo in your code (style part), your table also miss the ID property and there's no TD with the `amount_free` class on it.

Try with:

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#table_id td.amount_free').each(function(){
            if ($(this).text() == '0 €') {
                $(this).css('background-color','#f00');
            }
        });
     });
</script>
</head>
<br><br>
<style>
table, td {
    word-wrap: keep-all;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, th { 
    border: 1px solid black;
}
th, td {
    padding: 3px;
}
th {
    text-align: left;
}
th {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
td{
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
</style>
    <table style=width:100% id="table_id">
        <tr>
            <th>table</th>
            <th>system</th>
            <th>timestamp</th>
            <th>total_amount</th>
            <th>amount_used</th>
            <th>amount_free</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>amount_values</td>
            <td>users</td>
            <td>2019-07-18 00:00:00</td>
            <td>398 €</td>
            <td>179 €</td>
            <td class="amount_free">0 €</td>
        </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `id` for `table` tag and `class` name for your specific `td` tag in your example. So your html code would be like below:

```
 <!–– add id to table ––> 
<table id="table_id" style=width:100%>
  <tr>
    <th>table</th>
    <th>system</th>
    <th>timestamp</th>
    <th>total_amount</th>
    <th>amount_used</th>
    <th>amount_free</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>amount_values</td>
    <td>users</td>
    <td>2019-07-18 00:00:00</td>
    <td>398 €</td>
    <td>179 €</td>
    <!–– add class to td ––> 
    <td class="amount_free">0 €</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

you are checking for a table with id `table_id` which doesn't exist. You are further checking a td-element with the class `amount_free` which also doesn't exist.

If you add ID and class then it will work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#table_id td.amount_free').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == '0 €') {
      $(this).css('background-color', '#f00');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table,
td {
  word-wrap: keep-all;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 3px;
}

,
th {
  text-align: left;
}

,
th {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

,
td {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 10pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table style="width:100%" id="table_id">
  <tr>
    <th>table</th>
    <th>system</th>
    <th>timestamp</th>
    <th>total_amount</th>
    <th>amount_used</th>
    <th>amount_free</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>amount_values</td>
    <td>users</td>
    <td>2019-07-18 00:00:00</td>
    <td>398 €</td>
    <td>179 €</td>
    <td class="amount_free">0 €</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```